# How to filter image to throw away stray pixels?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have image data that comprises mostly roundish images surrounded by boring black background. I am handling this by grabbing the bounding box using PIL's getbbox(), and then cropping. This gives me some satisfaction, but tiny specks of grey within the sea of boring black cause getbbox() to return bounding boxes that are too large.

A deliberately generated problematic image is attached; note the single dark-grey pixel in the lower right. I have also included a more typical "real world" image.

[Generated problematic image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXOP0.png)
[Real-world image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT46o.jpg)

I have done some faffing around with UnsharpMask and SHARP and BLUR filters in the PIL ImageFilter module with no success.

I want to throw out those stray gray pixels and get a nice bounding box, but without hosing my image data.

Comment: can you please elaborate on your question. Currently it's quite unclear what you are trying to do. Post your input image, the output you got and your desired output in the question

Comment: 'tiny specks of grey within the sea of boring black' seems to be noise. Remove them before applying`getbbox()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to run a **median** filter on a copy of your image to get the bounding box, then apply that bounding box to your original, unblurred image. So:

- copy your original image
- apply a median blur filter to the copy - probably 5x5 depending on the size of the speck
- get bounding box
- apply bounding box to your original image.

Here is some code to get you started:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter

# Load image 
im = Image.open('eye.png').convert('L')
orig = im.copy()    # Save original

# Threshold to make black and white
thr = im.point(lambda p: p > 128 and 255)
# Following line is just for debug
thr.save('result-1.png')

# Median filter to remove noise
fil = thr.filter(ImageFilter.MedianFilter(3))
# Following line is just for debug
fil.save('result-2.png')

# Get bounding box from filtered image
bbox = fil.getbbox()

# Apply bounding box to original image and save
result = orig.crop(bbox)
result.save('result.png')
```

[image]